# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module in NodeJS Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to write tests with Jest in my Express Typescript application. In the test files, when I am import functions from another file, I get  `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.
This is my package.json-

```
{
  "name": "customer-cart-service",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "handler.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --verbose ./tests"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "serverless-http": "^2.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb": "^3.209.0",
    "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb": "^3.209.0",
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.108",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.4",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "serverless-bundle": "^5.5.0",
    "serverless-dynamodb-local": "^0.2.40",
    "serverless-offline": "^11.2.3",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
}
```

This is my tsconfig.json-

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",                                 
    "module": "commonjs",  
    "baseUrl": "./",                  
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "node_modules/*",
        "src/@types/*"
      ]
    },          
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "removeComments": true,  
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, 
    "strict": true, 
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true, 
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,  
    "alwaysStrict": true, 
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true 
  }
}
```

add.ts-

```
import { add1 } from "../functions/add"

it('simple test',()=>{
    expect(add1(2,3).toBe(5);
})
```

add.ts-

```
export function add1(a:number,b:number) {
    return a+b;
}
```

Whatever I try, I am unable to resolve this error- SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module. Adding "type":"module" as shown in many solutions did not work.

Comment: Can you post your `jest.config.js` file?

Comment: There is no jest.config.js file

Answer (score 0):

This is because your code is being compiled to CommonJS as seen in your tsconfig. Changing the `module` field to `ESNext` should fix the issue.

Read more about ES modules here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html

Comment: I tried that as well. No change. I am getting the same error again.